# Are there extra considerations when writing data to Mongo's "local" DB?

Tags: mongodb, local-database

EDIT: 
There are a few points of view here

**Writing to "local" is a legitimate technique** - from "MongoDB: The Definitive Guide, 2nd. ED" and http://www.kchodorow.com/blog/2010/10/27/bending-the-oplog-to-your-will/

> This database will never be replicated and can be used to store any
>   collections that should be local to a single server

**Writing to "local" is never a good idea** - from https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-11670 and https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/E_aPgNR1zss

> it is not ok to write anything to local database - it is for
>   MongoDB's use and using it for user collections (to avoid replicating
>   them) is not guaranteed to not cause problems

**It may or may not be a good idea** - the documentation at http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/local-database/ is agnostic

---

Original post:

I'm encountering errors when writing about 100MB of data to the "local" DB on my Mongo 2.4.9 installation (both Windows and Linux versions).

This bug (https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-11670) looks similar to my problem, but I can't believe that randomly failing to write to a database is a minor issue, and that it will be put off until 2.7.  So it has to be me.

Anyway, the Windows errors look like this:

```
Fri Jan 24 15:59:11.551 [conn40] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\util\stacktrace.cpp(167)                           mongo::printStackTrace+0x3e
Fri Jan 24 15:59:11.551 [conn40] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\dur.cpp(277)                                    mongo::dur::DurableImpl::_aCommitIsNeeded+0xe8
Fri Jan 24 15:59:11.551 [conn40] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\instance.cpp(812)                               mongo::insertMulti+0x212
Fri Jan 24 15:59:11.551 [conn40] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\instance.cpp(875)                               mongo::receivedInsert+0xaff
Fri Jan 24 15:59:11.552 [conn40] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\instance.cpp(441)                               mongo::assembleResponse+0x57a
Fri Jan 24 15:59:11.552 [conn40] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\db.cpp(194)                                     mongo::MyMessageHandler::process+0xfa
Fri Jan 24 15:59:11.552 [conn40] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\util\net\message_server_port.cpp(207)              mongo::PortMessageServer::handleIncomingMsg+0x578
Fri Jan 24 15:59:11.552 [conn40] mongod.exe    ...\src\third_party\boost\libs\thread\src\win32\thread.cpp(180)  boost::`anonymous namespace'::thread_start_function+0x21
Fri Jan 24 15:59:11.552 [conn40] mongod.exe    f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_64_amd64\crt\src\threadex.c(314)      _callthreadstartex+0x17
Fri Jan 24 15:59:11.552 [conn40] mongod.exe    f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_64_amd64\crt\src\threadex.c(292)      _threadstartex+0x7f
Fri Jan 24 15:59:11.553 [conn40] kernel32.dll                                                                   BaseThreadInitThunk+0xd
Fri Jan 24 15:59:11.553 [conn40] ERROR: can't commitNow from commitIfNeeded, as we are in local db lock
```

And the Linux errors look like this:

```
Sat Jan 25 00:20:04.558 [conn19] ERROR: can't commitNow from commitIfNeeded, as we are in local db lock
0xde46e1 0x921a65 0x921b4c 0x9f8b15 0x9f9412 0x9ffd68 0x6e8518 0xdd0cae 0x7f0cd72d8ddb 0x7f0cd667ca1d
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x21) [0xde46e1]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo3dur11DurableImpl16_aCommitIsNeededEv+0x155) [0x921a65]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo3dur11DurableImpl14commitIfNeededEb+0x4c) [0x921b4c]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo11insertMultiEbPKcRSt6vectorINS_7BSONObjESaIS3_EERNS_5CurOpE+0x45) [0x9f8b15]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo14receivedInsertERNS_7MessageERNS_5CurOpE+0x862) [0x9f9412]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo16assembleResponseERNS_7MessageERNS_10DbResponseERKNS_11HostAndPortE+0xab8) [0x9ffd68]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo16MyMessageHandler7processERNS_7MessageEPNS_21AbstractMessagingPortEPNS_9LastErrorE+0x98) [0x6e8518]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo17PortMessageServer17handleIncomingMsgEPv+0x42e) [0xdd0cae]
 /lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0x7ddb) [0x7f0cd72d8ddb]
 /lib64/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d) [0x7f0cd667ca1d]
```

The errors are intermittent, but usually occur in blocks for 30-90 seconds and during that time I can't write any data.  Several times I have had to kill the process that writes the data.

Speaking of data, I'm writing about 750,000 fairly simple documents (a handful of strings and a small embedded document).  No user-specified indexes, just the default index on _id.

Can I expect to write to the "local" database without errors?  I read that this was a legitimate technique for data that you did not want to replicate.

Are there any workarounds to this?  Special configuration settings?  I'm using the default configuration for the Windows install and slight log modifications for the Linux install

Comment: The `local` database is only intended to be used for MongoDB replication and other internal tracking. In general, writing to the `local` database isn't a good idea especially if this is the primary of a replica set. Where did you read that it was a legitimate technique?

Answer (score 0):

Are you running in a replica set? If so, the reason you see writes be blocked is all other threads need to write to the oplog which will need to grab the write lock on the local DB.

Reading the code, it looks like MongoDB will try to commit data on the insertion thread if the amount of uncommitted data passes a certain threshold, but will not do so if you are using the local DB or the admin DB. So, when you repeatedly try to write to the local DB and MongoDB wants an insertion thread to commit data, the thread doing these local DB writes may thrash.

Assuming you have other threads doing writes, I SUSPECT, that a possible workaround would be to sleep for a short time when you get this error, to give another thread a chance to commit the journal without holding the local DB. But this is speculation from reading the code.

Comment: My plans are to run on a replica set, but I'm still testing overall workflow on a single instance right now.  The client code doesn't actually get any errors back - it just hangs on a socket read I think - so I can't do any error detection and sleep or whatever.  Good idea, though.

Answer (score 0):

The `local` database is only intended to be used for MongoDB replication and other internal tracking.

As per Asya's comment on [SERVER-11670](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-11670):

> regardless of this ticket, it is not ok to write anything to local database - it is for MongoDB's use and using it for user collections (to avoid replicating them) is not guaranteed to not cause problems (other than this problem you already ran into).".

In this issue she was testing the new `$out` feature of aggregation against the oplog, which is why the affected version is 2.5.3 (development/unstable) and the fixVersion is uncertain.

If you want to write data that won't be replicated, your best approach is to setup a separate standalone `mongod` instance. There is not (as at MongoDB 2.4) a supported way to store your own non-replicated data in a replica set deployment.

Comment: I saw that response to my comment after I had posted this question to SO - the idea that you cannot write user data to local is entirely new to me, and not supported by the documentation that I've read.  Have I missed some other docs?

Comment: @EdNorris: I think there is a rather subjective distinction to make. Technically you *can* write to the `local` database (there is nothing preventing you from doing so).  Practically this is not a tested or supported configuration, so doing so may cause unexpected problems (such as what you are reporting here). In my experience, it's definitely more problematic than helpful and I wouldn't recommend writing to the `local` database in production.

Comment: @EdNorris: It is also worth noting that both Asya and I work for MongoDB, Inc so our viewpoint is based on customer experience in aggregate. If writing to the `local` database works for your use case, that's great .. but I don't think it's a good or recommendable idea at the moment (i.e. addressing your question of "should this be expected to work without errors").

Comment: A former employee of MongoDB wrote books and blog posts that disagree with that, and while I believe you that it is a bad idea to write to the local db, I'm a little concerned about the discrepancy.  I'll head by the MongoDB office next week during the "office hours" meetup and see what I can find out.

Comment: @EdNorris: I'm aware that Kristina wrote the Definitive Guide, but perhaps something has changed to make `local` less recommendable since then. Which office hours are you planning on going to (SFO, NYC, ...)?